# Hive permissions appear to be removed after Spark overwrite

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am granting permissions to roles using the following Hive statement:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_table TO ROLE some_role;
```

Now, after this DDL is run the user is able to run a select on the table. If I run my spark job (which has ALL permission on the table and which overwrites the table) then the user is no longer able to run the select and receives the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException No valid privileges User xxx does not have privileges for QUERY The required privileges: Server=server1->xxx->Table=xxx->Column=processing_effective_time->action=select->grantOption=false;
```

If I run `hdfs dfs -getfacl <path to db>`

I see that the `some` group for which select was granted (previously with r-x permission) no longer appears in the ACL.

This seems to imply that Hive table access permissions are actually HDFS file access permissions under the hood.

Does this in turn mean that I have to (re)-grant select privilege from my Spark job every time I overwrite a table?

Cheers

Terry

Comment: There are several authorization models for Hive -- using Ranger plugin, using Sentry plugin, and multiple "native" (read "crude and not bulletproof") models. You don't explain which one you use.

Comment: As you can see, Spark has little respect for Hive attempts at emulating a DBMS -- does not honor read/write locks, tramples "native" permissions, etc >> either use Sentry / Ranger to enforce the permissions at Metastore & HDFS levels (in a coercitive way), or set **inheritable** ACLs manually at the root Table level e.g. `hdfs dfs -setfacl -m default:group:some:r-x <path-to-table>`

Comment: Caveat: if Spark actually re-creates the Table root dir, instead of just emptying it, then you must set the ACLs at DB level -- which has unfortunate side effects for other tables...